# How can I disable all battlegrounds in-game?

Tags: azerothcore

How do I disable all the battlegrounds from game?

I can disable Wintergrasp in config, but what about others? I tried looking for settings in both config and dbc files but couldn't found such option.

Any hep would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/disables
For anything related to disables.
It's just a line of SQL per BG.

Comment: Great, thanks for pointing me towards the right direction. I have read the wiki but that page somehow evaded me.